# Prevent Bootstrap Modal to show on Page Load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

This is for the first time I'm facing something like this... very strange!

I have modal dialog code at the bottom of the page (just before the body tag) which is filled in with data by PHP at later time.

```
<!-- email dialog -->
<div id="ewEmailDialog" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ewButton">
                    <?php echo $Language->Phrase("SendEmailBtn") ?>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ewButton" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <?php echo $Language->Phrase("CancelBtn") ?>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've jQuery and Bootstrap JS loaded in correct order in the footer of the page. Whenever the page is loaded a blank Modal dialog shows up. There is no code on `$(document).ready(function() {});` and yet the modal dialog shows up.

I searched here and found a few similar questions posted. The solutions proposed over there didn't work for me. I tried following...

1. Add `hide` class. This works but then modal does not show on button click either.
2. Make sure bootstrap js is loaded `after` jQuery. Yes, that's the way scripts are loaded.
3. See if there is any function that triggers `modal('show')`. I checked and there is no such jQuery call.
4. Latest versions of jQuery and Bootstrap... yes.

I'm still not sure why the modal keeps on showing up. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Cheers,

Ruturaaj.

Comment: If you create a snippet or fiddle, then it is easy to find the exact problem instead of showing your list of proposed solutions.

Comment: don't see an issue with your snipped i've created a fiddle to test works fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/riazxrazor/rz2f9o5u/

Comment: Surprisingly, I'm not able to reproduce this issue at jsfiddle.

Comment: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ruturaaj/6fz2505e/

So I think there is some conflict somewhere with the other scripts that I'm using, like fullcalendar, excanvas, chart.min.js. I will try to recreate this issue on jsfiddle; something is surely wrong somewhere.

Comment: This JSFiddle will show you the issue that I'm talking about. 
https://jsfiddle.net/ruturaaj/rerLuvp9/2/

I referred to the documentation of old version of Bootstrap (v2.x which our designer has used), but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could reproduce the error. HTML Code structure is same as before...

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="main-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="alert alert-info">
                            Page Content goes here.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /main-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- /main -->

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span12">
                        &copy; 2017
                        <a href="#">Bootstrap Responsive Template</a>
                        .
                    </div>
                    <!-- /span12 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /container -->
        </div>
        <!-- /footer-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->

    <!-- modal dialog -->
    <div id="ewModalDialog" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--## if (bUseModalLookup) { ##-->
    <!-- modal lookup dialog -->
    <div id="ewModalLookupDialog" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--## } ##-->
    <!--## if (bUseAddOpt) { ##-->
    <!-- add option dialog -->
    <div id="ewAddOptDialog" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ewButton">
                        <?php echo $Language->
                        Phrase("AddBtn") ?>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ewButton" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <?php echo $Language->
                        Phrase("CancelBtn") ?>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--## } ##-->
    <!--## if (bUseEmailExport) { ##-->
    <!-- email dialog -->
    <div id="ewEmailDialog" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ewButton">
                        <?php echo $Language->
                        Phrase("SendEmailBtn") ?>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ewButton" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <?php echo $Language->
                        Phrase("CancelBtn") ?>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--## } ##-->
    <!-- message box -->
    <div id="ewMsgBox" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ewButton" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <?php echo $Language->
                        Phrase("MessageOK") ?>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- prompt -->
    <div id="ewPrompt" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ewButton">
                        <?php echo $Language->
                        Phrase("MessageOK") ?>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ewButton" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <?php echo $Language->
                        Phrase("CancelBtn") ?>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- session timer -->
    <div id="ewTimer" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ewButton" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <?php echo $Language->
                        Phrase("MessageOK") ?>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </
```

However, the Bootstrap version is older one. See the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ruturaaj/6fz2505e/

I thought Designer has used latest Bootstrap; but it's `version 2.3` what he has used in the design (and the reason best known to him).

> So, (at least in my case) the issue of `Modal Dialog showing up on Page
>   Load` seems to be related to old version v2.x of Bootstrap. When I replaced the
>   `Bootstrap v2` with `Bootstrap v3.x`, everything started to work well (with some CSS conflicts of course; may the designer now deal with it!).

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following style to modal div

```
    <div id="ewEmailDialog" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" 
    style="display:none">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">
    </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ewButton">
    <?php echo $Language->Phrase("SendEmailBtn") ?>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ewButton" data-
    dismiss="modal">
    <?php echo $Language->Phrase("CancelBtn") ?>
    </button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think this is same like adding `hide` class.

Comment: @RuturajPatki using 'hide' class the modal popup doesn't appear. Please check the fiddle-https://jsfiddle.net/samsonthekkekara/ZcLSE/1606/

Answer (score 0):

Call the modal on page load by calling the ID.

```
$(function(){
  $("#myModal").modal()
})
```